# how is array(0) different from array()

Tags: php, arrays

```
$variable = array(0);

$variable = array();
```

how are they different?

Comment: total noob here...how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case :

```
$variable = array(0);
var_dump($variable);
```

You get :

```
array
  0 => int 0
```

ie, an array with an element whose value is 0.

And, in the second case :

```
$variable = array();
var_dump($variable);
```

you get :

```
array
  empty
```

ie, an empty array.

Answer (score 9):

The first populates an array with a number 0, the latter is an empty array.

Comment: Correct. And thus the first one has an element in it, while the second one does not (it is empty).

Answer (score 7):

The first contains a single element, a integer zero. The parameter is not a "size initializer" as you might imagine. You can see this by using var_dump on them:

```
$foo = array(0);
var_dump($foo);

$bar = array();
var_dump($bar);
```

This outputs

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
}
array(0) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to meder:

```
$variable = array(0);
count($variable); // 1
empty($variable); // false
(!$variable)  // false

$variable = array();
count($variable); // 0
empty($variable); // true
(!$variable)  // true
```